# Is there a way to upgrade nodejs 10 in an AWS CodeBuild managed image?

Tags: node.js, aws-codebuild

I need nodejs runtime in AWS CodeBuild. I have tried substituting the v10.16.0 which comes packaged with codebuild with v11.14.0 but when I check `node -v` output it still shows as 10.16.0.

Can anyone help me fix this ?

TIA.

Comment: How do you check nodejs version? Provide your `buildspec.yml` or something the same.

Comment: node -v is what I am going with. But it always takes what comes pre installed in the aws managed image which is 10.16.0. My buildspec uses a relative path to node.exe but that isn't working. The path is relative to $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR since I have manually (curl approach) downloaded and unzipped nodejs 11.14.0 to the filesystem location with the $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR as root location.

Comment: Do you define `Runtime Version` in your `buildspec.yml`? like https://github.com/dvohra/node-js/blob/master/buildspec.yml

Comment: Currently I am using a runtime-version of "java:openjdk8". My build stack is a combination of nodejs+ant+jdk. I have tried both options - with/without explicit nodejs runtime declaration in the buildspec but neither has helped. I am contemplating a chocolatey install of nvm and see what options I have from there.

Comment: I think Codebuild just supports runtime in the list https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html . You can try use a custom Docker image instead of the image what managed by Codebuild.

Comment: I have tried my custom docker image on CodeBuild. Just wont work even though I have tested these images successfully on Windows 2016 and Windows 2019 DataCenter edition. :| The only option I have right now is CodeBuild FWIW.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this by `curl`downloading nodejs 11.14.0 from within the buildspec and overriding the default environment variable for `PATH`.